# Renderizar un componente dentro de un Mat-Tab de Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

Estoy buscando la manera de hacer que una Tab de angular material, pueda renderizar un componente dentro del contenido de la tab, estoy renderizando la tab de este modo.
HTML.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(asyncTabs | async) === null">
  Loading tabs...
</ng-container>

<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs | async">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
    {{tab.content}}
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

De esta manera tengo mi ts.

```
import {Observable, Observer} from 'rxjs';

export interface ExampleTab {
  label: string;
  content: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-async-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-async-example.html',
})
export class TabGroupAsyncExample {
  asyncTabs: Observable<ExampleTab[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.asyncTabs = new Observable((observer: Observer<ExampleTab[]>) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next([
          {label: 'First', content: component},
          {label: 'Second', content: component},
          {label: 'Third', content: component},
        ]);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

Pero aun asi no puedo ver el contenido de mis html de mis componentes funcionando.

Comment: He intentado con navigateByUrl no ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto cambiando toda la forma.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> <may-app></may-app> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> <may-app></may-app> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> <may-app></may-app> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

No era la forma que buscaba pero por lo pronto es la mejor manera que tengo, ya que, queria conservar el setTimeout.
Si usted tiene otra forma que sea por el typescript, por favor deja tu comentario.